# Error <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: php, android-studio, webservice, jsonobject

Tengo una app creada en android studio con java, estoy haciendo un login que se conecta a una base de datos "externa"(El servidor es mi ordenador) y tengo creado un web Service en php para que realize la consulta, el problema es que me da el siguiente error ya dicho en el titulo

> br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject.

al pulsar el boton de login, no se muy bien donde esta el error si en el php o en el codigo de android studio
Este es el código de **android**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button button;
private EditText emailLogin, contrasenaLogin;
private static String URL_LOGIN = "http://192.168.1.133/login.php";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    emailLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);
    contrasenaLogin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailLogin);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           String mEmail = emailLogin.getText().toString().trim();
           String mPass = contrasenaLogin.getText().toString().trim();

           if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()) {
               login(mEmail, mPass);
           } else {
               emailLogin.setError("Inserta un email");
               contrasenaLogin.setError("Inserta una contraseña");
           }
        }
    });

}

private void login(final String email, final String contrasena){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");

                if(success.equals("1")){

                    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){

                        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        String email = object.getString("emailLogin").trim();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success Login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", contrasena);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}


public void regist(View v){

    Intent myintent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Registro.class);
    startActivity(myintent);

}
}
```

Aquí el codigo **php**

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

$email = $_POST['emailLogin'];
$password = $_POST['passLogin'];

$base = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'id10437812_bdwet') or die ("No se pudo conecta a la BD");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_table WHERE email='$email' ";

$response = mysqli_query($base, $sql);

$result = array();
$result['login'] = array();

if ( mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1 ) {

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response);

    if ( password_verify($password, $row['Contraseña']) ) {


        $index['email'] = $row['emailLogin'];


        array_push($result['login'], $index);

        $result['success'] = "1";
        $result['message'] = "success";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($base);

    } else {

        $result['success'] = "0";
        $result['message'] = "error";
        echo json_encode($result);

        mysqli_close($base);

    }

}

}

?>
```

Por lo que e leido habia solucciones diciendo que era porque habia que poner la conexion a la base de datos en el propio php, pero aun asi tampoco funciona

¿Puede ser que el error resida porque tengo las claves encriptadas en la base de datos?

Comment: Si imprimes el valor de "response" dentro del método onResponse(String response) el valor no es un json, comenta que es lo que e obtiene en tu pregunta.

Comment: El fallo se encuentra en que el php esta recibiendo datos en blanco debido a que cuando hago el put la etiqueta esta mal escrito en el php y en vez de email pone emailLogin

Comment: ok la respuesta no era apropiada para ser "parseada" como Json. Es un error que no se puede reproducir en el caso de nosotros la comunidad.

Comment: Claro, al principio pense que era algo del json debido a que me fijaba más en las conexiones y todo lo demas del php que en los get del php, de todos modos gracias por tu ayuda